# What are the security controls around IBM Bluemix DevOps Services?

Tags: ibm-cloud

In the evaluation of Bluemix DevOps Services, I have a few questions:

- Where is Bluemix DevOps Services hosted?
- Is the code in the Git repository backed up, and is the backup encrypted?
- Are there audit logs on the access of the source code in the Git repository?

The only question I found which is similar is https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/16102/ibm-devops-services-security.html , but the response does not provide any details.

The FAQ ( https://hub.jazz.net/docs/faq/ ) does not mention security at all.

Comment: You should contact https://support.ng.bluemix.net/technicalsupport/ for this sort of question. It's too broad in scope for this site.

Comment: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html is the right place for questions about Bluemix offerings and capabilities.

Comment: Ok will do, thank you.